# My outputs in 4bits fullAdder are always z and don't change

Tags: verilog, active-hdl

I'm writing 4 bits full adder with verilog in Active-hdl I think my code and test-bench are right but the value of sum and cout are always z in waveform can anybody help me what the problem is.this my code and test-bech

```
    module fullAdder(A, B, cin, sum, cout);
    input A,B,cin;
    output sum,cout;
    assign {cout , sum} = A + B + cin;
endmodule

module fullAdder4bits(A, B, cin, sum, cout);
    input [3:0] A,B;
    input cin;
    output [3:0] sum;
    output cout;
    wire w1,w2,w3;
    fullAdder I0(A[0],B[0],cin,sum[0],w1);  
    fullAdder I1(A[1],B[1],w1,sum[1],w2);
    fullAdder I2(A[2],B[2],w2,sum[2],w3);
    fullAdder I3(A[3],B[3],w3,sum[3],cout);
endmodule   
`timescale 1 ns/1 ps  
module testbench;
    reg tcin;
    reg [3:0] tA,tB;
    wire [3:0] tsum;
    wire tcout;
    fullAdder4bits dut(tA, tB, tcin, tsum, tcout);
    initial 
        begin
        tA = 0;
        tB = 0;
        tcin = 0;
        #10 tA = 5;
        #10 tB = 8;
        #10 tA = 7;
        #10 tcin = 1;
    end
    initial $monitor("A = %d , B = %d , cin = %b , sum = %d , cout = %b",tA,tB,tcin,tsum,tcout);  
    initial #60 $finish;
    endmodule
```

[image: the output in waveform]

Comment: can you help in run the test-bench? I followed these steps : 1- right click on test-bench and click initialize simulation 2- select all inputs and outputs 3-right click and choose Add to waveform and finally run it

Comment: I cant understand what happend in active-hdl So I use compiler and online simulator and see my output this is the link : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/23eb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not spot any errors so I decided to throw your design at Vivado.

It helps that you have given the complete code inclusive test-bench!

Your code seem fine and in Vivado I do not see the 'z' status:

[image]